# Is testing for node existence in XML required/recommended in ActionScript 3?

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

The following is example of reading XML with ActionScript 3

```
var xml:XML = 
    <content>
        <a>Hello A</a>
        <b>Hello B</b>
        <c>
            <c1>Child C1</c1>
            <c2>Child C2</c2>
        </c>
    </content>;


trace(xml.a); // OP: Hello A
trace(xml.c.c1); // OP: Child C1
trace(xml.d); // OP: (nothing)
trace(xml.b);; // OP: Hello B
```

I don't see the `xml.d` outputting an empty string as expected behavior? Is this normal? What is the reasoning for this?

To me, I 'feel' like I should be doing this:

```
if(xml.d) trace(xml.d);
```

Is it ok to rely on the empty string behavior? IE do I need to check for a node's existence??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`xml.d` is XMLList. Since node doesn't exist, this list will be empty.
You can test node existence with `xml.d.length()` (gives count of nodes d) or `xml.d[0]` (gives first node d, will be null in this case).

Comment: Now this is the answer I was looking for. I wasn't clicking that xml.d (or any variation on this, such as xml.d.d.d.) will return an XMLList. In saying this, XML must be a dynamic class as because otherwise it would throw an error 'd is not a property or method of xml' but I still don't see how it's 'typing' it's dynamic variables. For example if I created a class, there is no way I know of that I could make it so someone could write the following: var myClass:MyClass = new MyClass(); myClass.a.f.g and g is typed as an xml list.

Comment: XML (and XMLList) is not only dynamic class, it is even *magical* in some way. `xml.d` is in fact *xml selector* in simple form. Selectors always return XMLList, and xml.d.d.d is just a chain of calls. You can even make something similar by inheriting from Proxy class, but this is out of scope of question.

Comment: I was actually going to say that it must be 'special' in someway, because it is far from standard behavior. Excellent answer overall though, and great follow up. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the only Time I have ever had issues with empty child nodes is if i was trying to assess children of the empty node. So yeah in that case you need to test for empty string.

```
if(xml.d != "" ) trace(xml.d);
```

You might want to also read up on [e4x](http://dispatchevent.org/roger/as3-e4x-rundown/)

Comment: IMO, `xml.d != ""` is always true, since XMLList is never equal to String. If you cast xml.d to String, that would be different case.

Comment: Did you even test what I posted? If the node does not exist xml.d will return an empty string which will make it false. If the node exists it will return the xml node making it true.

Comment: fyi xml.c will convert to a string. so var str:String = xml.c is acceptable.

Comment: I did test. `xml.d != ""` is always true, whether node exists or not. XMLList can be compared with String only after converted/casted to String.

Comment: Then you need to retest because it is NOT always true

Comment: And the string conversion is automatic

Answer (score 0):

If you try to access properties or methods of a non existent node, the AVM will throw an error. You should wrap any code that might fail for a known reason in a `try{} catch(){}`.

here's a good explanation: http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?p=1957523

Comment: Thanks for the answer, try/catch blocks aren't appropriate in this case as the AVM doesn't throw an error. This is the documented behavior of the XML class